# "Running Applications Only" Dock mode Stuck!

Tags: dock

Recently I have stumbled upon a trick that will allow you to view *only* your running applications within the dock. The Terminal command was:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock static-only -bool TRUE
```

This would hide all of the "pinned" apps that were on the dock, and only show the active/running apps.

When I found out I was ecstatic, but slightly cautious (due to the fact that it may not be reversible).

I changed TRUE to FALSE and saw that it could easily be changed.

Now, for some reason, the Dock won't change back. I've tried running the command as root, rebooting, restarting the Dock, restarting the Finder, restoring TEMP files, closing and opening all running applications, and more.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried deleting that exact file? Preferences' System File are restored automatically (with default values) if not found.

Comment: And how about restarting your machine? Does that help?

Comment: Just `defaults write com.apple.dock static-only -bool false; killall Dock` undid it for me. Have you tried removing `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist`? Are there even any applications that are set to be kept in Dock?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Thecafremo who just answered my question!
(Unfortunately, I cannot mark a comment as an answer.

> *Have you tried deleting that exact file? Preferences' System File are restored automatically (with default values) if not found. - Thecafremo*